# What happens if I get all 10 Splatfest shells?

Tags: splatoon-3

> When a player wins a 10× battle during a Splatfest, they earn a festival shell.
> When multiple players on a team hold a lot of festival shells, the chances of getting into a 100× battle are increased. If both teams in a match each trigger a 100× battle, a rare 333× battle occurs instead. After a 100× or 333× battle happens, the players involved have their festival shells disappear.

This is what the [official Splatoon wikia](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Festival_shell) states.

The shellmeter shows that you can get up to 10 Splatfest shells. What happens when a player maxes them out in an *unlucky* streak of no 100x matches? Will I have a guaranted 100x match? Is there some kind of reward?